# When will the Winter Bash 2015 begin?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

When will the Winter Bash 2015 begin?   Any info on the non-secret hats?

Comment: In 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: The hell are you tweaking about? It's already on, here's a screenshot of this page

Comment: It's almost a certainty that Winter Bash will occur again starting in December 2015. It's never too early to start asking questions about it.

Comment: Could have sworn someone already asked about this.  Maybe on [meta.so]... Anyhow, they shipped the hats with all the #SOReadyToHelp swag. So it'll probably be another month or so.

Comment: Trying to claim that elusive *"anxious for winterbash to start"* hat?

Comment: You've ruined it by asking.

Comment: @bluefeet: 3 hours early (for december) isn't too bad. It's nearly been a year since the last one!

Comment: http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ hmmmmm

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/214536/revisions) it's soon, and it confirms at least one hat for this year. ;)

Comment: @animuson Is pardoning a turkey enough?  And how do we provide proof? Should I send the live turkey to the offices in New York?

Comment: @Won't I asked some time ago, but too many downvotes and seemed nobody was interested.

Comment: Winter Bash is on!

Comment: Winter `bash` again? That's, like, shell favoritism or something. Those of us who prefer `ksh`, `zsh`, or `fish` like to celebrate (and keep our heads warm) in the winter, too. (Even those `tcsh` folk are entitled to their beliefs, too...)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's started.

---

Given the [countdown clock](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), it will start December 13th, 2015 at 7pm EST (4pm PST), which is the start of December 14th, 2015 in the GMT time zone.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what that "clock" represents... 5 digits doesn't really tell me much.

Comment: @Werner the countdown is simply the number of minutes until it starts. You can time how long it takes to countdown one unit to verify it's counting minutes, then calculate the time it'll reach zero, or read the source code.

Comment: What source code?

Comment: @PythonMaster http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/countdown.js

Comment: @AndreasFester Is there a properly formatted version?

Comment: @PythonMaster I assume that the real source is not disclosed, but you can get started by copy&paste the compressed javascript into a javascript beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ - it still has the obfuscated variable names then, but its much easier to read ...