# Effect of down votes

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, up-votes

I asked [a question about Winterbash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270189/when-will-the-winter-bash-2015-begin).  Before asking that question, I had 101 points, one for joining and 100 bonus.  Now I have 113, although I cannot tell how many positive or negative votes I have on my question.  Did I get to keep the first 10 points and got voted down thereafter and lost subsequent points, or what?

Answer (score 5):

Check [your reputation tab](//meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation). It will show the positive and negative changes to rep, as well as votes that did not change your rep.

Because of the association bonus, all votes affect your rep: -2 for every downvote, +5 for every upvote.