# When will Winter Bash 2016 begin?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

I noticed [the 2016 Winterbash URL](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) has been made active, but there is no countdown yet.

[image]

When will we start hatting? Is there a deadline by when sites can opt in/out?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 because people hate fun? Or just because people prefer to let SE declare it on their own time.

Comment: Because generally we don't like users being impatient. Why not wait until it is there?

Comment: Calm down folks: [When will the Winter Bash 2015 begin?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270189/168244)

Comment: Here's a motivation behind my question: On [tex.se] we've opted out of Winterbash for the first couple of years, but joined in on 2015. Based on knowledge of a timeline, one could [ask again on Meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6406/5764) what the community's interest is in participation.

Comment: Maybe you should ask about the deadline then? Isn't that more relevant?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Good point. I've updated my question to be less open-ended, specifically asking about an opt-in/-out deadline.

Comment: Anyway, guess we'll know when it begins in 6-8 weeks

Comment: Haters gonna hate. Hatters gonna hat.

Comment: It's official. Countdown started.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

#### The winter bash starts on December 19, 2016 and runs up to and includes January 8, 2017.

Sources:

http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4143
[Winter Bash 2016!](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2258/2217)
[Should we stay opted-in for Winter Bash 2016?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7072)
an email sent from SE to all moderators.

Comment: Good my head is getting real cold, I need at least 20 hats to keep it warm.

Answer (score 36):

Soon....

> [image]

As far as the site opt in/out, I'll be sending out the emails (hopefully) this week. Blame Turkey Day for it not getting out last week.

Comment: Turkey Day? Are they a new hire? ;)

Comment: Will we know when it begins before it ends? ;)

Comment: Everything is a secret this year @ShadowWizard

Comment: So will I get a secret hat if I guess when Winterbash begins this year? ;)

Comment: No hats for guessing, sorry @ShadowWizard.

Comment: That's what I guessed @bluefeet ... hat pls.

Comment: My ban finger is twitchy @Bart :P

Comment: Flipper. Your ban flipper. We ponies have hooves, you penguins have flippers. We both don't have "real" fingers.

Comment: How dare you call me a penguin @SPArchaeologist!!!!

Comment: *Checks SE Staff Memes book* ... Nope, seems right. You are a penguin, Gracenote is **the** Cactuar, Shog is either Cthulhu, a medusa head from Castlevania or both, Jason is a beard.... The guide says so, and the guide is always right. Only reality can be quite imprecise at times :P

Comment: @SPArchaeologist not a penguin, but a [blue footed booby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-footed_booby).