# Do moderators still indicate their interest before hats are turned on for their sites?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

The [Winter Bash FAQ page](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/faq) includes the following question every year.

> **Why are you doing this to us?**
>
> For sites that have hats on by default, your moderator teams or your communities indicated that hats would be a fun, lighthearted thing to do. [ ... ]

I'm aware that moderators used to receive an email informing them on the duration of Winter Bash and that Winter Bash was held on a per-site opt-in basis (and there were actually [sites that opted-out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245183/do-all-sites-have-winterbash)). [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287412/when-will-winter-bash-2016-begin/287571#287571) appears to be the latest year I could find when [such an email](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/winter-bash-2016) was sent out to moderators.

Do moderators still get a heads-up email informing them of the start of Winter Bash and for them to indicate their site's interest in Winter Bash? If not, is the FAQ page technically incorrect since all sites are now automatically opted-in to Winter Bash?

Comment: Might be small oversight, so adding [tag:bug] tag.

Comment: The only site that's ever opted out is MathOverflow so we just stopped asking. Not an oversight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope - there’s no email any longer on the sites I am a mod. In the past (aka the early days of Winterbash), some communities would post a Q/A on their meta, effectively asking “do we want to participate” and posting two answers (in short, “yes” and “no”), to give their members a chance to vote. Haven’t seen this either in a while.

Conclusion:
As long as nobody actively lobbies to opt out, participating is the default. And for the individual user, they can always “bah, humbug” by clicking “No hats for me, please” and be done with it, without impeding those who love Winterbash. The others get to wear the SE equivalent of the *Ugly Sweater* or make a dash for the leaderboard.

I would assume that *at some point* the various mod teams have either opted in or not opted out, and we can take that as “valid until stated otherwise”, so the FAQ is not necessarily incorrect, as the FAQ doesn’t say “indicated *for this season*”.

Comment: [You cannot please everyone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403841/make-hats-opt-in-rather-than-opt-out).