# When do the holiday hats start appearing again for late 2018?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

When will the holiday hats start being awarded again on the Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Yes it is for 2018/2019 season.  BTW, I don't understand all the down votes.  Its just a question that I am sure a number of people are wondering.

Comment: Look at [last years question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303371/winter-bash-2017-when-will-it-start-this-year), [or the year before that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287412/when-will-winter-bash-2016-begin), [or the year before that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270189/when-will-the-winter-bash-2015-begin)

Comment: Last years [start question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303371/158100) was asked mid november and has a score of +36/-14. With +7/-15 you're on track.

Comment: *sigh*..........

Comment: @Eran changing _hats start appearing_ to _hats start being awarded_ is a completely unnecessary minor change. If this is an attempt to earn something (badge, hat) please make useful edits.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We have a [countdown](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)!

[image]

It looks like Winterbash 2018 will begin on Wednesday Dec 12 '18!

I must admit that's 5 days earlier than I expected.

It's consistent with last year's Wednesday Dec 13 '17 start date, but I thought they'll go back to the tradition of starting Winterbash on Monday.

Comment: Hopefully they remembered to filter out potentially offensive numbers like 80085.

Comment: Huzzah! Having a countdown rocks.

Comment: Would be awesome if you can make the image dynamic somehow. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard maybe I should replace it every day or so :)

Comment: Nah, just write code that scrapes the countdown, turns it into image, and host it somewhere. Piece of cake! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard why would I need to scrape the countdown? I know when the countdown will reach 0, so I can calculate the current value myself.

Comment: Oh, so take the current image as background and put dynamic number on it.... yeah that can work either. Unless SE change their countdown appearance... ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - My version is dynamic, feel free to edit for better accuracy.

Comment: @PeterJ they did not (just saw 480085 on the countdown), though why would anyone find that number offensive? (I do realize is slightly resembles a certain word, but still, it's just a number).

Comment: @Eran it wasn't a serious comment, but seemed appropriate given all the recent meta posts where people seem to find new and amazing ways to be offended by just about anything

Answer (score 7):

This site counts down with a GIF: https://www.sendtric.com/

[image: Winter Bash 2018]

BTW: It [ends Jan 1 2019 @ 0:00 AM](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/faq)

[image: Winter Bash 2018]

Comment: You should subtract 4 hours off this counter.

Comment: Not using the winterbash design but still nice. As @Eran said, it's not accurate and I don't know how it's working so can't edit to fix it. Cheers! :)

Comment: So as not to bump my answer I'll add this information in a comment. Despite what the FAQ says the *hat* called: "[Glasses With A Number On Top](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/glasses-with-a-number-on-top)" is earned by: "Post a message in chat within **±** 12 hours of the UTC New Year’s begin that gets starred" - that suggests that Winter Bash 2018 ends 12 hours after what is written in the FAQ.

Comment: And, the Community Manager's Blog says [Jan 2 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/).